# Django: passing value to template from DetailView context not working

Tags: django

I see the following error when trying to render my `item_detail` template, which uses a url tag in a link to the item_update view:

```
NoReverseMatch at /mcadb/27/items/17
Reverse for 'item_update' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'course_id': '', u'pk': 17}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'mcadb/(?P<course_id>[0-9]+)/items/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/update/$']
```

What is the problem trying to match the pattern tried? Is it because of the `u`? I'm not sure why that is happening.

In views.py, I try to add '`course_id`' to the context for the DetailView. I try to get 'course_id' from the kwargs for the view (I don't know why it's blank)

views.py

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    DetailView.model=Item
    template_name='mcadb/item_detail.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ItemDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['course_id'] = self.kwargs['course_id']
        return context
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<course_id>[0-9]+)/items/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='item_detail'),
url(r'^(?P<course_id>[0-9]+)/items/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/update/$', views.ItemUpdate.as_view(), name='item_update'),
```

item_detail.html

```
<a href="{% url 'mcadb:item_update' course_id=course_id pk=item.id %}">Edit Item</a>
```

The problem is with the 'course_id=course_id' line. If I change it to 'course_id=26', item_detail.html renders fine.

I have two questions. 
1. what does the error mean, when it looks like I'm passing two kwargs as expected? 
2. why does it work if I hardcode a course_id? 
Thank you very much, Carrie

Comment: Are you sure that `self.kwargs['course_id']` has the right value?

Comment: No, I'm not sure.  I probably have two issues. First - setting course_id in get_context_data. Given the url pattern for item_detail, I don't know why that line isn't working. Second, even if that's not making a correct assignment, that shouldn't be the cause of the error I'm seeing (I think). If I set course_id= 27 in get_context_data, it still raises the error.

Comment: Raises the same error? set course_id to an static value, eg. 27 and try like this: `<a href="{% url 'mcadb:item_update' kwargs={'course_id': course_id, 'pk': item.id} %}">Edit Item</a>`

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I tried as you suggested, I get a TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '{'course_id':' from '{'course_id':'

Comment: @Pynchia: `kwargs` and `self.kwargs` inside `get_context_data` are totally different, and by default kwargs passed to `get_context_data` won't contain any of values from `self.kwargs`.

Comment: I think you have an error in your html, please show more HTML

Comment: So @GwynBleidD, are you saying that I can't access the kwargs of the view (as defined in the url pattern) in get_context_data? If that's true, then I'm going about this the entirely wrong way.

Comment: @Gocht, I can't paste my whole html file right now. But the first problem seems to be at the view, and it seems that even if {{ course_id }} was the only thing in my template, it wouldn't have a value.

Comment: If you do in view this: context['course_id'] = 26 and then in template: {{ course_id }} it does not print anything?

Comment: @Gocht, that's correct. Does that give insight?

Comment: @Carrie no, I mean that @Pynchia misunderstood what `kwargs` and `self.kwargs` are in that case. But his comment is gone now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the error:

```
url(r'^(?P<course_id>[0-9]+)/items/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='item_detail'),
```

Note that you are use a generic `DetailView` (from `django.views.generic.DetailView`) with this url.

You need to use your own View `myapp.views.ItemDetailView`.

So in your `urls.py` file:

```
from myapp.views import ItemDetailView

url(r'^(?P<course_id>[0-9]+)/items/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='item_detail'),
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes complete sense, and I just wasn't seeing it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Explanation for your exact error is here:

> Reverse for 'item_update' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'course_id': '', u'pk': 17}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'mcadb/(?P[0-9]+)/items/(?P[0-9]+)/update/$']

As you can see, reverse is getting empty `course_id` and URL can't be built with empty, because there must be at least 1 number (+ sign in regex pattern). so there is definetly something wrong with passing `course_id` into context or into url tag. Try to print that variable next to `url` tag and check it's value. Check if you can access this variable somewhere else in your template (maybe outside of all for loops, includes and `with` tags) and if you can access it directly from your view (try to create URL here using reverse or just print variable to logs).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now I understand where the error is coming from. I have tried printing course_id {{ course_id }} in my template, and it's definitely not getting set. Even if I set context['course_id']=27 in get_context_data, {{ course_id }} is still nothing in the template.